Synapse how to copy pipelines between branches?
We have 3 synapse workspaces (dev, test, maint) connects to it's own branch in the same Azure DevOPs repository. We also have feature branches based off the dev branch. All our development is done using Azure Synapse Studio.
We want to pull the changes from the feature branches into the dev branch and eventually the test and maint branches. We do not want anything published to "live" mode. We simply want the changes brought in from dev to test and then to maint.
Our linked services have the same names between dev, test, and maint BUT they are using different integration runtimes.
If we do a simple pull request from dev to test, it will use the wrong integration runtime because the same linked service uses a different runtime between dev and test.
How do we solve this?

Have you tried any approach so far?

To promote changes from Dev to Test and then to Maint in Azure DevOps,
You can use a branching strategy where you can work on feature branches in the "Dev" environment,
Next merge those changes into a "Test" branch for testing, and finally merge to a "Prod" branch for production deployment,
All managed through your Azure DevOps pipeline with automated build and deployment stages for each environment.
Below are the steps you can follow:

Select New > New release pipeline & select a template and start a empty job
Select the stage and rename it to Dev so the configured stage can be triggered when an artifact is published from DEV branch.
Under Artifacts, click Add to include a new artifact.  Choose your Source type and complete the required fields Once finished, click Add to confirm.
Click on the Continuous deployment trigger icon and enable it to automatically create a release whenever a new artifact becomes available.
In the Dev stage, click on the Pre-deployment conditions icon and set the deployment trigger to After release.  This will trigger the deployment to this stage each time a new release is created.
While still in Pre-deployment conditions, enable Artifact filters,click Add, select the previously chosen artifact, and set the Build branch to Dev.

In the next steps Know more about Adding a new stage & Deploy to a specific stage
